# ゼロから作るDeep Learning 5章 誤差逆伝番の実装をXorの実装に変更したい

Tags: python

「ゼロから作るDeep Learning 第5章」に記載してある誤差逆伝番の実装を使用して、Xorの判定を可能にしたいです。
Google colaboratoryを使用し構築しています。

参考にしたページ:
[ゼロから作るDeepLearning 5章を学ぶ 〜誤差逆伝播法〜](https://www.takapy.work/entry/2018/06/07/223928)

上記ページは下記コード変更前の誤差逆伝番の実装となります。
こちらURLの実装に関して、データはGitHubに掲載してあるmnistを使用せず、kerasのデータセットを使用し、Google Colaboratoryで正常に動作しました。
(下記「データ読み込み」部分に記載してあるものが使用していたもの)

この上記URLの実装を下記のように変更後、コードを実行すると値は出力されますが、正答率は収束せずに終了しています。
どのようにすれば、正確な値が出力され、学習、評価が正確に行われるのでしょうか

- 書籍に掲載されているコードではSoftmax_WithLossを使用していますが、今回のLastLayerでは、Sigmoid_WithLossを使用しています。
- 損失関数は交差エントロピー誤差から2乗和誤差に変更しています。
- 書籍では入力・出力データとしてMnistを使用していますが、今回はXorの判定としてtrainとtestのデータは同じものを使用しています。

使用したコードは以下になります。

```
 from keras.utils.data_utils import dont_use_multiprocessing_pool
 class affine:#行列演算レイヤ
    def __init__(self,W,b):
        self.W = W
        self.b = b

        self.x = None
        # 重み・バイアスパラメータの微分
        self.dW = None
        self.db = None

    def forward(self, x):

         self.x = x
         out = np.dot(x, self.W) + self.b
         return out

    def backward(self,dout):
        dx = np.dot(dout, self.W.T)
        self.dW = np.dot(self.x.T, dout)
        self.db = np.sum(dout, axis=0)

        return dx

class Sigmoid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.out = None

    def forward(self, x):

        self.out = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        return self.out

    def backward(self, dout):
        dx = dout * (1.0 - self.out) * self.out
        return dx


def mean_squared_error(y,t):
  return 0.5 * np.sum((y - t)**2)
  


def numerical_gradient1(f, x):
    h = 1e-4 # 0.0001
    grad = np.zeros_like(x)

    it = np.nditer(x, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])
    while not it.finished:
        idx = it.multi_index
        tmp_val = x[idx]
        x[idx] = tmp_val + h
        fxh1 = f(x) # f(x+h)

        x[idx] = tmp_val - h
        fxh2 = f(x) # f(x-h)
        grad[idx] = (fxh1 - fxh2) / (2*h)

        x[idx] = tmp_val # 値を元に戻す
        it.iternext()

     return grad

# Sigmoid with Lossレイヤの実装
class SigmoidWithLoss:
    
    # 初期化メソッドの定義
    def __init__(self):
        self.params = [] # パラメータ
        self.grads = []  # 勾配
        self.loss = None # 損失
        self.y = None # 正規化後の値
        self.t = None # 教師ラベル
    
    # 順伝播メソッドの定義
    def forward(self, x, t):
        self.t = t # 教師ラベル
        # 確率に変換
        self.y =self.out = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        # 2乗和誤差を計算
        self.loss =  mean_squared_error(np.c_[1 - self.y, self.y], self.t)
        
        return self.loss
    
    # 逆伝播メソッドの定義
    def backward(self, dout=1):
        # バッチサイズを取得
        batch_size = self.t.shape[0]
        
        # 勾配を計算
        dx = (self.y - self.t) * dout / batch_size # :式(A.4)
        
        return dx
```

```
from typing import Collection
import numpy as np
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict


class TwoLayerNet:

    def __init__(self, input_size, hiden_size, output_size, weight_init_std = 0.01):
        self.params = {} #辞書
        self.params['W1'] = weight_init_std * np.random.randn(input_size, hiden_size)
        self.params['b1'] = np.zeros(hiden_size)
        self.params['W2'] = weight_init_std * np.random.randn(hiden_size, output_size)
        self.params['b2'] = np.zeros(output_size)

# レイヤの生成
        self.layers = OrderedDict()#OrderedDict は順番を含めて覚えるため、レイヤー名と処理を順次登録すると、その順番も含めて記憶する。
        self.layers['Affine1'] = affine(self.params['W1'], self.params['b1'])
        self.layers['Sigmoid1'] = Sigmoid()
        self.layers['Affine2'] = affine(self.params['W2'], self.params['b2'])
        self.lastLayer = SigmoidWithLoss()
        

    # 順伝播
    def predict(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers.values():#辞書 self.layers からレイヤー名を順番に
            x = layer.forward(x)
        return x

    # 順伝播・ロス計算(最終層の順伝播処理であり損失関数)
    def loss(self, x, t):
        y = self.predict(x)
        return self.lastLayer.forward(y, t)

 # 精度計算
    def accuracy(self, x, t):
        y = self.predict(x)
        y = np.argmax(y, axis=1) #argmaxで、数値が高いラベルのみを取り出す。
        if t.ndim != 1 :#1次元ではない場合
             t = np.argmax(t, axis=1)# argmaxで、正解のラベルを取り出す。

        accuracy = np.sum(y == t) / float(x.shape[0])#y==tがTrueのものを１として合計して、それをデータの総数で割り算する。
        return accuracy

    # x:入力データ, t:教師データ
    # 数値微分、重みパラメータに対する勾配を求める
    def numerical_gradient(self, x, t):
        loss_W = lambda W: self.loss(x, t) # lambda 無名関数、lambda x: y ,xが引数で、yが返り値
        # def loss_W(W):self.loss(x,t) と同じ意味。つまりdefのように関数を作らず使用

        grads = {}
        grads['W1'] = numerical_gradient1(loss_W, self.params['W1'])# １層目の重みの勾配。損失関数と、重みから算出。
        grads['b1'] = numerical_gradient1(loss_W, self.params['b1'])# 1層目のバイアスの勾配。損失関数と、重みから算出。
        grads['W2'] = numerical_gradient1(loss_W, self.params['W2'])# 2層目の重みの勾配。損失関数と、重みから算出。
        grads['b2'] = numerical_gradient1(loss_W, self.params['b2'])# 2層目のバイアスの勾配。損失関数と、重みから算出。

        return grads

        # 重みパラメータに対する勾配を誤差逆伝播によって求める。
    def gradient(self, x, t):
        # forward
        self.loss(x, t)
        # backward
        dout = 1 
        dout = self.lastLayer.backward(dout) # 出力層の逆伝播を求める。

        layers = list(self.layers.values())#layersをリストにする。
        layers.reverse()# 逆の順番にする。
        for layer in layers:
            dout = layer.backward(dout) #各レイヤーの逆伝搬の値を算出する。

        #各レイヤの微分値取り出し(勾配の保持)
        grads ={}
        grads['W1'] = self.layers['Affine1'].dW 
        grads['b1'] = self.layers['Affine1'].db
        grads['W2'] = self.layers['Affine2'].dW
        grads['b2'] = self.layers['Affine2'].db

        return grads
```

```
# データの読み込み
import numpy
import sys, os
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# visualization tools
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#(x_train, t_train), (x_test, t_test) = mnist.load_data()#normalize=False, one_hot_label=False)
#x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
#x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
#print(x_train[0,0])
# データを float 型に変換
#x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
#x_test  = x_test.astype('float32')


# 0〜255 までの範囲のデータを 0〜1 までの範囲に変更
#x_train /= 255
#x_test  /= 255
#t_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(t_train, 10)
#t_test  = keras.utils.to_categorical(t_test, 10)


#print(x_test)
#print(t_train.shape)
#print(t_test.shape)

x_train = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]])
t_train = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])
x_test = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]])
t_test = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test  = x_test.astype('float32')

network = TwoLayerNet(input_size=2, hiden_size=2, output_size=2)
iters_num = 1000 # 更新回数
train_size = x_train.shape[0] #訓練データのサイズ

batch_size = 1 # バッチサイズ
learning_rate = 0.1 # 学習率

# 正答率の表示頻度
iter_per_epoch = max(train_size / batch_size, 1) # 1エポックあたりの繰り返し数

train_loss_list = []
train_acc_list = []
test_acc_list = []

for i in range(iters_num):#ミニバッチ生成
    # 0~(train_size-1)の中から重複ありランダムで抽出
    batch_mask = np.random.choice(train_size, batch_size)
    x_batch = x_train[batch_mask]
    t_batch = t_train[batch_mask]
    # 誤差逆伝播法によって勾配を求める
    grad = network.gradient(x_batch, t_batch)

    # パラメータの更新
    for key in ('W1', 'b1', 'W2', 'b2'):
        network.params[key] -= learning_rate * grad[key]

    loss = network.loss(x_batch, t_batch)
    train_loss_list.append(loss)

    if i % iter_per_epoch == 0:
        train_acc = network.accuracy(x_train, t_train)
        test_acc = network.accuracy(x_test, t_test)
        train_acc_list.append(train_acc)
        test_acc_list.append(test_acc)
        # 正答率の表示
        print(train_acc, test_acc)
# グラフの描画
markers = {'train': 'o', 'test': 's'}
x = np.arange(len(train_acc_list))
plt.plot(x, train_acc_list, label='train acc')
plt.plot(x, test_acc_list, label='test acc', linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel("epochs")
plt.ylabel("accuracy")
plt.ylim(0, 1.0)
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: 「書籍に既存しているコードでは、Softmax_WithLossを使用していますが、
今回のLastLaerでは、softmax_WithLossを使用しています。」とありますが、softmax_WithLossの記述が見当たりません。どの箇所でしょうか？

Comment: 損失関数とデータを書籍のコードから変更しているようですが、変更前のコードでは正しく学習できていた、ということで良いでしょうか？

Comment: @merino softmax_withLossの文章に関しては自分の記述ミスです。今回は使用していません。
変更前の損失関数、データを用いた場合では正しく学習できました。
少し内容を追加いたします。